# Restoring multiple databases in a SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Could you advise please, or point me in the direction of an appropriate article that could help.

I need to upgrade a SQL 2008 R2 instance to SQL 2019. I am proposing to backup the databases in the source instance and restore to a new more up-to-date host server. What is the best way to go about the restores of these many databases without doing them one at a time? Thank you

Comment: How many databases are there?

Comment: @J.D. thank you for your time. 50 databases some  of which are dependent on each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use either of the following tools to accomplish restoring multiple databases at one time:

1. [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) - I've personally never used it but have heard many good things. I believe requires a bit of scripting.
2. [Microsoft's Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) - Has a GUI and can proactively point out issues with migrating to the new server. But can be a little bit of a pain in some oddball scenarios. Overall a good tool, in my opinion though.

Or you could generate your own SQL restore scripts a number of different ways. For example, you could [sys.databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and / or [sys.database_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: thank you so much for your help as always. I'm sure I will find these suggestions useful. Much appreciated.